# Laravel 5 SQL Relations

Tags: php, sql, laravel, laravel-5

I have some problem with a query in Laravel.
I want to create a filter query by column in server table but I don't know how to do this.

Need help to modify the following line:

```
$data = $video->files()->with('server')->get();
```

Model: server

```
public function files()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\File', 'id', 'server_id');
}
```

Model: file

```
public function server()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Server', 'server_id', 'id')->ordered();
}
```

My current query return this:
(but it returned all, I need return only FILE flitered by type = 6 which is server table) I don;t know how to do this. On screen below data about type server is on #relations array 
[image]

Comment: Hey, please clear your table relationship because it is too confusing to understand. you fire query on video table trying to get the relationship from server table? it does not make sense. what is the relationship between video table and server table?

Comment: video has data about name,size,views. One video can be on few servers so in file table I stored on which servers the file are. Servers have data about servers because is more than one

Comment: Check now first post. I added new img.

Answer (score 0):

Use `WhereHas`. Takes the relation name and a closure as a parameter, where you can define sub query like functionality with the relation.

```
$data = $video->files()->with('server')->whereHas('server', function ($query) 
{
    $query->where('type', '6');
})->get();
```